# cassandra 2.2.8: How to add node to cassandra dataCenter /Cluster with minimum impact

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I added a new node to Cassandra cluster by making it seed node and than started rebuilding it (nodetool rebuild ) command. Although node joined the cluster quickly, the rebuild process that started streaming from all nodes in selected  caused the whole dc nodes to slow down. The impact on application is severe. I'll have to stop rebuild process in order to keep normal operation ON!.

Here, I'm seeking advice if you guys can share ways/tricks so to minimize the impact of (node rebuild ) operation on rest of dc nodes and application.

I'll much appreciate your suggestions - thanks for reading my message and your help in advance.

Comment: According to this you just have add more nodes to your cluster: http://grokbase.com/t/cassandra/user/163y4cdfqh/speeding-up-nodetool-rebuild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you added a node as a seed node just so it will not bootstrap and join the cluster instantly. While is approach is right for it joins the cluster quickly, the downside is, it will not bootstrap and hence will not copy all the data from other nodes that it is responsible for. When you run a rebuild on that node, data is blindly copied (without doing any validation) from other nodes, which can choke up existing nodes throughput and your network pipeline. This approach is very safe and is recommended when using adding a new DC but not when adding nodes to an existing DC.

When you are adding a node, the simplest way is to add a node using the procedure described here. https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html

When the node bootstrap, it will copy data needed from other nodes but will not start taking client connections until it fully bootstraps and validates the data. So, add one node at a time and let it bootstrap so all the necessary data is copied and validated. After you are done adding the number of nodes you desire, run a cleanup on all the previously joined nodes to cleanup all the keys for which the old nodes are not responsible.

Comment: Thank you Vincent Khedkar for your reply. much appreciate your insights

Answer (score 2):

While adding a new node you shouldn't make it a seed node. The seed node is used to bootstrap other nodes and join them in cluster. Making the new node as a seed node will not allow to join the new node in the cluster. Follow the steps provided in the Cassandra docs provided in the link below.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html

This is the best way to add a new node in the cluster.

**Note: Make sure the new node is not listed in the -seeds list. Do not make all nodes seed nodes. Please read Internode communications (gossip).**

Comment: [Making the new node as a seed node will not allow to join the new node in the cluster.] May i beg to disagree, you claim is not correct. I already went thru this exercise i.e. to make new node as seed node so it skip bootstrap and join the cluster swiftly.. that part is already over.. here i'm seeking guidance as how to mitigate affect of node rebuild operation that is causing strain on referenced DC nodes

Comment: Why are you rebuilding the node?. Rebuild is necessary when you are adding a new Data center, but adding a new node to existing cluster doesn't require rebuild. You must run cleanup and can run repair to make sure the cluster have required number of replicas.